# How to use gulp-webserver proxies property?

Tags: javascript, server, gulp, proxy-server

I have a little issue with understanding of proxies of gulp-webserver package.
I need to proxy my localhost 8080 to make it accessible from the outside. But I don't quite understand how I can do it with gulp-webserver proxies property.
Here I have my piece of code:

```
gulp.task('server', function(){
    gulp.src('dist')
        .pipe(webserver({
            livereload: true,
            open:true,
            port:8080,
            proxies:[
                {
                    source:'/hello', 
                    target:'http://localhost:8080/hello'
                }
            ]
        }));
});
```

1. So such proxy has to give acces by simply entering the address http://localhost:8080/hello in any browser?
2. For what reasons this "proxies" is using?
3. How can I make my localhost accessible from outside with gulp?

Answer (score 0):

Just answer one of you question and you should understand the rest.

To use a proxy in this development environment setup is to get around the CORS (google it). Your ajax call can not simply make a call to another domain / server address; you can actually, but your browser security policy will stop you from doing it, there are ways to get around it. And while you are developing. Most likely you have a http://localhost domain name. And the actual end point is sitting else where.

So for example in your ajax call

```
$http.post('/api', data);
```

You are actually making calls to http://localhost/api

Which doesn't exist (unless you have a full backend running). So for example you have a real backend running from http://real.com/api. By setting up the proxy with your gulp setup.

whenever you point to /api it will go out to http://real.com/api to fetch the data for you.

If you want to access the development outside your local machine. All you have to do is to set the gulp-webserver `host` to `0.0.0.0` then from the outside you need to find out your machine address (for example 192.168.0.1)

And from your browser on the other machine just type http://192.168.0.1:3000 (the 3000 is the property of the `port`) and you should able to see your local machine serving up the content.